# UBUNTU 18.10 - Error 15 http://grub4dos.chenall.net/e/15

Tags: dual-boot, 18.10, grub4dos

I can't install (dual-boot) Ubuntu 18.10 on my laptop. Right now i have only Windows 10 installed. Rufus, UUI and other usb bootable programs do the same thing: After changing Boot Setup in BIOS to my external drive being 1st and then restarting the system it shows something like:

> Error 15: grub4dos.chenall.net/e/15 not found
>
> initrd casper/ILUG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't dualboot Ubuntu (STILL)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091674/cant-dualboot-ubuntu-still) The newer question you posted has more up-to-date information, so this one is the duplicate question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was re-posted by OP